# if (an) is a sequence of non negative numbers , and (an) is k-th power summable for some k > 0, then (an) is also j-th power summable for all j > k.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I am trying to prove this statement, I want to know if this is the right proof that worked on. If not, please help me prove this

I know that for a sequence (an) of real numbers and a real number k > 0, we say that (an) is
k-th power summable if Σan^k converges.

TO PROVE THIS STATEMENT,

I supposed a sequence (an) is k-th power summable, then that means Σan^k

now since j>k i.e. j>0 since k>0 then

Σan^j is also summable due to Σan^k

because if Σan^k  is summable then Σan^k converges
which implies that lim(n->infinity) an^k = 0
and j>k implies
lim(n->infinity) an^j = 0
therefore
Σan^k is also summable

also, what can be examples of sequences that are 10th power summable but not 9th power summable? and example of sequences that can be 9th power summable, not 10th?

Comment: $\ lim_{n->\infty} a_n^{j}= 0$ does not imply that $ Σa_n^{j}$ is summable .

Comment: after finitely many terms, $0\leq a_n^k<1$. Then after finitely many terms we have  $0\leq a_n^j\leq a_n^k<1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Can I use induction to prove this?

Comment: Please have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and re-fromat you question accordingly.